# Create column based on distinctive sets of multiple row values

Tags: r, dataframe, grouping

I want to identify unique sets of row values in a column based on row values in another column to ultimately create a new column in the dataframe. The following picture illustrates my problem and the expected result (i.e., the `expected_outcome` column).

For example:

- The first 3 rows have values `T1` in the column `trial`, and values `D1, D2, D3` in the column `group`.
- The next 3  rows have values `T3` in the column `trial`, and values `D3, D2, D1` in the column `group`.

Because the set `D1, D2, D3` has the same contain as `D3, D2, D1`, I want all the 6 rows to have the same value in column `expected_outcome`.

My data is way more complex than that. I may have to make this grouping over more than 2 columns. So, I prefer a generic solution to this problem. Below is the data in the picture.

```
test_data <- data.frame(
  trial            = c("T1", "T1", "T1", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T5", "T5", "T6", "T6", "T6"),
  group            = c("D1", "D2", "D3", "D3", "D2", "D1", "D1", "D3", "D1", "D3", "D2")
)
```

[image: Data and expected result]

Comment: So the `expected_outcome` is the same when two trials contain exactly the same groups?

Comment: T6 has also D1 D3 D2?

Comment: Yes @tavdp! But I need the grouping to account for row values sequence in group column too.

Comment: @TarJae, this is correct! The last row should be T7 instead of T6. I updated the picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the last `trial` in your column should be `T7`?

```
library(dplyr)

test_data %>% 
  arrange(across(everything())) %>% 
  group_by(trial) %>% 
  mutate(expected_outcome = toString(group)) %>%
  group_by(expected_outcome) %>% 
  mutate(expected_outcome = cur_group_id())
```

```
    trial group expected_outcome
   <chr> <chr>            <int>
 1 T1    D1                   1
 2 T1    D2                   1
 3 T1    D3                   1
 4 T3    D1                   1
 5 T3    D2                   1
 6 T3    D3                   1
 7 T5    D1                   2
 8 T5    D3                   2
 9 T6    D1                   2
10 T6    D3                   2
11 T7    D2                   3
```

data:

```
test_data <- structure(list(trial = c("T1", "T1", "T1", "T3", "T3", "T3", 
"T5", "T5", "T6", "T6", "T7"), group = c("D1", "D2", "D3", "D3", 
"D2", "D1", "D1", "D3", "D1", "D3", "D2")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

Comment: Each of the 3 answers solved my problem but I found this one truly elegant!

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this via `tidyverse`.

```
library(tidyverse)

test_data %>%
  group_by(trial) %>%
  summarize(type = paste(sort(unique(group)), collapse = ", "), group) %>%
  group_by(type) %>%
  mutate(expected_outcome = cur_group_id()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  dplyr::select(-"type")
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 11 × 3
   trial group expected_outcome
   <chr> <chr>            <int>
 1 T1    D1                   1
 2 T1    D2                   1
 3 T1    D3                   1
 4 T3    D3                   1
 5 T3    D2                   1
 6 T3    D1                   1
 7 T5    D1                   2
 8 T5    D3                   2
 9 T6    D1                   1
10 T6    D3                   1
11 T6    D2                   1
```

**Data**

```
test_data <-
  structure(list(
    trial = c("T1", "T1", "T1", "T3", "T3", "T3",
              "T5", "T5", "T6", "T6", "T6"),
    group = c("D1", "D2", "D3", "D3",
              "D2", "D1", "D1", "D3", "D1", "D3", "D2")
  ),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA,-11L))
```

Answer (score 2):

<sup>**Note: This answer is based on the [original problem](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/70503798/1) before OP was edited, where groups had to be identified by themselves without an erroneous `'trial'` column.**</sup>

`factor`ize group column and, using `ave` calculate `cumsum` of `duplicated`s in each group. Then, where even numbers appear, `cumsum` the differences that equal `1`.

```
(test_data <- within(test_data, { 
                    group_int <- as.integer(as.factor(group))
                    group_2 <- ave(group_int, group_int, FUN=\(x) 
                                   cumsum(duplicated(x)))
                    expected_outcome <- cumsum(c(1, diff(group_2 %% 2 == 0)) == 1)
                    rm(group_int, group_2)
}))
#    trial group expected_outcome
# 1     T1    D1                1
# 2     T1    D2                1
# 3     T1    D3                1
# 4     T3    D3                1
# 5     T3    D2                1
# 6     T3    D1                1
# 7     T5    D1                2
# 8     T5    D3                2
# 9     T6    D1                2
# 10    T6    D3                2
# 11    T6    D2                3
```

**Note:** R >= 4.1

---

*Data:*

```
test_data <- structure(list(trial = c("T1", "T1", "T1", "T3", "T3", "T3", 
"T5", "T5", "T6", "T6", "T6"), group = c("D1", "D2", "D3", "D3", 
"D2", "D1", "D1", "D3", "D1", "D3", "D2"), expected_outcome = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L)), row.names = c(NA, -11L
), class = "data.frame")
```